# How to vertically center text overlapping an image?

Tags: html, css

How can I get text centered vertically on an image? I already made a setup on how it should look but I can't get the text to be centered on every image because they have different heights.

I have already tried using the "top" property and vertical-align and methods mentioned in other questions but nothing seems to work for this situation.

Is there anyway this can be achieved?

The JSfiddle can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/Sf3RX/2/

HTML

```
<div class="column">
<div class="image">
    <img src="/">
    <p class="info">cats
        <br><span>#Photography</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    .image {
    position: relative;
    width: 25%;
    text-align: center;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
}

p.info {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
    top: 25%;
}
```

Comment: Is the Image size dynamic or you can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to achieve this result http://jsfiddle.net/paulalexandru/MSfPs/ all you have to do is to :

Adjust your css like this:

```
p.info {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
    top: 25%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

And add this javascript code also:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $(".image").each(function() {
            var height_image = $(this).find('img').height();
            var height_p = $(this).find('p.info').height();

            var rest = height_image - height_p;
            $(this).find('p.info').css('top', rest/2);
        });
    });
</script>
```

The javascript code calculates the css top property for every `<p>` in order for them to be in the middle of the block.

Another pure css solution is to change your html code a little bit, you have to add a table height 100% / width 100% and set a vertical-align: middle on the `<td>` and inside it you should put the paragraph.

Comment: This solution worked perfectly! Had some trouble getting it to work with the actual page, but I figured it out. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try `line-height`, or `top:50%;margin-top://-the height of the Textblock`

Answer (score 0):

You can set `line-height` to 100%, which will make the line the same height as your image, vertically centering it.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TWKzp/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
body{
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
    margin:0px auto;
}
#main{
    position: relative;
width:500px;
height:500px;
}
#abc{
    text-align:center;
background-color:#0F0;
height:250px;
display: table;
width: 100%;
}

#abc span {
    vertical-align:middle;
display: table-cell;
}
</style>
<div id="main">
    <div id="abc">
        <span>asdfasdfafasdfasdf<br/> sdfjdsl flkjdsflk sjdflkjdsf </span>
</div>
</div>
```